# Requirements for cherry picking a single function out of jQuery Mobile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I'm interested in incorporating the jQuery Mobile Datetime text input capabilities into a hobby Rails app that I'm building. I do not need any of the other jQuery Mobile features.

What is the best way to go about this? Will it work if I include nothing but [the jquery.mobile.forms.textinput.js file from github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.forms.textinput.js) or are there other required jQuery Mobile files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know in the Release Notes for RC1 they had decoupled jQM and were working on a Download Builder

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/09/29/jquery-mobile-1-0rc1-released/

> **Download builder: In the works**
>
> Now that we’ve decoupled most of the UI widgets, we’ve set the stage
>   for there to be a download builder. This will let you build a custom
>   version of jQuery Mobile to only include the parts you need. For
>   example, you could just use the core files to add Ajax-based
>   navigation with pushState and leverage some of the touch events and
>   other utilities with a very lightweight build (roughly 10k). Or, you
>   could add in specific UI widgets like form elements, listviews, etc.
>   to create an optimized build. We’re aiming to have a download builder
>   tool launch as part of 1.0 final in some form. We’re working on a
>   dependency map now for all the plugins to support this tool.

Not sure if this is release as of yet

Comment: I awarded this the answer since it specifically addressed the jQM issue that I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no widget for a date/time picker packaged with jQuery Mobile at the moment.

There are however several options out there (and I'm sure you can find more with some Google-time):

http://mobiscroll.com/ - I use this one on mobile websites

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/ - Updated to work well with jQuery Mobile 1.0RC3, but note that it requires jQuery Mobile (see J.T.Sage's comment below).

Comment: Fwiw, jQM-DateBox does rely heavily on jquerymobile - it cannot be easily decoupled (I'll try to have a dependency list up when jQM has a download builder).

Comment: @J.T.Sage Thanks for the info. And thanks for the solid plugin. One comment/suggestion I'd like to make is that the icon to open the picker is quite small (especially for a touch event), what about binding to the click (or focus) event for the text input as well?

Comment: Jasper - that option is called 'noButtonFocusMode' - it hides the small icon, and turns the entire input element into the trigger - with the downside that it becomes very difficult to hand-input a date instead of using the controls (which might be a moot point - I think be default it is disallowed now)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mobiscroll. I'll give that a shot tomorrow. I like the look of jQM-DateBox but don't want to carry jQM to use it. FYI, iOS5 accepts `type="datetime` now to use the native datetime picker, but I'm having trouble passing values to it.